# Changing default header of Request in Babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-headers, request-promise

I am pretty new in Babel and trying to make a POST request with header "Content-Type" as "application/json". Is there any documentation for changing the headers of `Request` ?

```
  import Request from 'request-promise-native'
  const result = await Request
      .post(`some url`)
      .auth(authId, secretToken,false)
      .form({
        text: "hello"
      })
  console.log(result);
  return JSON.parse(result)
```

Comment: What does `Request` have to do with the Babel transpiler?!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a headers object like so:

```
.headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
})
```